# Need help with the definition of econometric terms

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Can somebody please explain in a simpler way, what is meant by "mean correctly specified" and "time averages of the covariates"?
These terms are used in the context of a panel data model.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not easy to answer without a reference to a source, but my take would be

1. The regression equation is correctly specified in the sense that all relevant predictors/regressors/covariates are included so as to be able to give a causal interpretation to the results. "Mean" may refer to the first moment of the dependent variable, so allowing for the possibility that there may be unmodelled effects in the second moments (the variance), e.g., heteroskedasticity.
2. With panel data, you have several observations for one unit over (typically) time. E.g., you observe several employees over several years.

Comment: This is the comment I received:
"In the panel data case, the correlated random effects approach requires you to compute the time averages of the time-varying covariates and add them. This is supposed to mimic fixed effects."

I have the data for 27 patients over the period of 5 weeks. And let's say one of the covariates is patient's weight which varies across all 5 weeks.. 
Can you please explain, what I am being suggested to do in that comment?

Comment: Let's say we have just two patients, you and me, observed over three weeks. Your weight is 70, 71, 72 in the three weeks, and mine is 76,77,78. Then your time average is 71, mine is 77.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Okay, that I understood. How do I add this to the data? I mean, my data is in columns, patient1, week 1, week 2, week 3....week5, and all the corresponding data in columns, then patient 2, from week 1 to 5, and all the corresponding data in columns... how do I add time-averages? 

Is it like, the same average of a particular variable repeated again and again for 5 weeks,  (written in columns)

p.s. sorry, i am not very technical with economics

Comment: that seems more like a programming question that will depend on the tool used (and in any case is off topic here)